# Golang channels causing deadlocks despite closing them before iterating through them

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I wish to have multiple goroutines that put a value each into a channel.
And after all the goroutines are finished executing, I wish to iterate through the channel and get all the values which were put into them.
Ideally I should perhaps use a synchronised collection for this, but as I am new to golang, I wanted to try and implement this with channels.

My program:

```
func main() {
    intArr := []int{3, 5, 6, 8, 2}
    channel := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(intArr))

    // For each number in intArr, cube the number and send it the channel
    for _, each := range intArr {
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            channel <- num * num * num
        }(each)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(channel)

    // Print all the numbers the channel received
    for each := range channel {
        println(each)
    }
}
```

I am:

1. Closing all the goroutines after they execute.
2. Closing the channel after all goroutines are done writing.

But still I keep seeing my code deadlock.
Execution output:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x14000090008)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x38
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x14000090000)
    /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x74
main.main()
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:21 +0xf0

goroutine 17 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0x14000090000, 0x1400008c060, 0x3)
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:18 +0x68
created by main.main
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:16 +0xd4

goroutine 18 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0x14000090000, 0x1400008c060, 0x5)
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:18 +0x68
created by main.main
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:16 +0xd4

goroutine 19 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0x14000090000, 0x1400008c060, 0x6)
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:18 +0x68
created by main.main
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:16 +0xd4

goroutine 20 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0x14000090000, 0x1400008c060, 0x8)
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:18 +0x68
created by main.main
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:16 +0xd4

goroutine 21 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0x14000090000, 0x1400008c060, 0x2)
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:18 +0x68
created by main.main
    /Users/varungawande/Desktop/untitled folder/test.go:16 +0xd4
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a buffered channel with length len(intArr)

```
channel := make(chan int, len(intArr))
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with it being an unbuffered channel?

Comment: Unbuffered channels don't have capacity so you have to read at the same time when any go routine is writing to it.

Comment: The channel writes are blocked, waiting for there to be capacity in the channel. Capacity can be made available by reading pending writes, but as you've written the code the reads only happen after all the writes have completed.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that since the channel `channel := make(chan int)` is blocking channel: when the channel is full, other goroutines must wait for it cause deadlock

One simple way to solve it, just put `wg.Wait()` to another goroutine

```golang
func main() {
    intArr := []int{3, 5, 6, 8, 2}
    channel := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(intArr))

    for _, each := range intArr {
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            channel <- num * num * num
        }(each)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(channel)
    }()

    // Print all the numbers the channel received
    for each := range channel {
        println(each)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/veddKPxFFwl

---

Another solution is to put the receive channel to another goroutine.

```golang
func main() {
    intArr := []int{3, 5, 6, 8, 2}
    channel := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(intArr))

    for _, each := range intArr {
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            channel <- num * num * num
        }(each)
    }

    go func() {
        // Print all the numbers the channel received
        for each := range channel {
            println(each)
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()
    close(channel)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why does it work if `wg.Wait()` and `close(channel)` are executed by a goroutine and not the main thread?

Comment: I just posted another sample to put `wg.Wait()` and `close(channel)` in the main thread.

Comment: I understand why the second solution works in context of a buffered channel. But not how the first solution works despite the channel being buffered.

Comment: The [`Fan-out, fan-in`](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines) may help you  @VarunGawande

Comment: Thanks, I will go through it. Also regarding my above question. I think I got it. The above approaches you gave are logically the same programs. The reading and the closing is happening on separate threads. In the first one, a goroutine waits to close while main thread reads. In the second one, a goroutine reads, while the main thread waits to close.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have an annswer, this case can be simplified like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    intArr := []int{3, 5, 6, 8, 2}
    channel := make(chan int) //create a channel

    go CubeIt(intArr, channel) // create a go routine

    for range intArr {
        fmt.Println(<-channel) // take out from channel
    }
}

func CubeIt(intArr []int, c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(intArr); i++ {
        cubed := intArr[i] * intArr[i] * intArr[i] // cube it heere
        c <- cubed // put in channel
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, appreciate the answer, but I was looking for ways of actually multiple goroutines, and not one. Also my intent behind the question was to actually use channels like a Queue of sorts.

Comment: @VarunGawande Ah I see. Just curious, do you think there is any advantage of doing that way? I believe you are creating a go routine for each value then cubing it.

Comment: In my actual application, I had a lot more processing per thread, and I wanted to collect the results of each thread at one place for the main thread to use after the multi-threaded application was over. But I couldn't use an array because some thread may not return a value. I could use a sparse-array but I didn't want to.